# How do I run in Angular 2 with Asp.net MVC using webpack?

Tags: debugging, angular, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, webpack

I have created a MVC (aspnet core) application that uses Angular2 for the front end.

A shortened version of my solution looks like this:

```
Solution
 - wwwroot (webpack bundled angular)
 |_ app.bundle.js (bundle)
 - app (angular 2 application)
 |_ Components
 |_ app.module.ts
 |_ main.ts
 - Controllers
 |_ HomeController.cs
 -Views
 |_Home
 -|_Index.cshtml
 -webpack.config.js
 -Startup.cs
 -project.json
 -package.json
 -web.config
```

My problem is when it comes to debugging and running the site.

I am using IIS express to debug the site.  It works, but debugging requires digging into an enormous webpack created `app.bundle.js`. (I'm not sure how to use the map files either.  Chrome doesnt seem to unpack them.)

Most of the documents I've read on debugging call for the use of `npm start` or `webpack-dev-server`.  I do not think I can use these because my site requires the `cshtml` to be served.

I would also like to get to a place where I can use `watch` to automatically compile and refresh my site.

Can I set up IIS (instead of express) to serve both cshtml and angular 2 files and debug them easily?  (preferably with something that handles updates like `watch`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the nuget package for core single page app's [Webpack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices/).  This integrates into your `Startup.cs` file.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Webpack;

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseWebpackDevMiddleware(new WebpackDevMiddlewareOptions
        {
            HotModuleReplacement = true,
            ConfigFile = "./webpack/webpack.config.js"
        });
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/App/Error");
    }

    app.UseStaticFiles();
```

You still configure the NPM Webpack as you would normally.  (note I am using `webpack.config.js` to do all the regular webpack configurations.)

The concept that was a little difficult to get my head around was that you are running 2 sites.  One (usually port 5000) that serves the CSHTML, the other (by default 8080 in the nuget webpack) that serves the angular 2 bundled javascript.

As for debugging in Chrome, use the `webpack://` tree in sources to set your breakpoints and step through your code.  And as @Kyle Trauberman notes be sure to enable sourcemap.

Comment: what if you are just using old asp.net mvc 5? how can we use hmr capability of webpack?

Comment: @RojBeraña are you asking this because you dont have a startup.cs or because you dont have a wwwroot?  If you dont have a startup.cs use OWIN, if you dont have a wwwroot, create the directory and use staticfiles and default files.  You may need to configure the static files middleware to map your wwwroot as root

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure the .map files are generated and served alongside the js bundle.  This will tell the debugger (chrome, for example) to map back to the original source file.

Ensure the `"sourceMap"` setting in your tsconfig.json file is set to `true`.

http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html